# Vmware: enable VIX programmatically?

Tags: vmware, vix

I found that it is possible to query if VIX is enabled by doing a `VixVM_ReadVariable()` for the variable `"vmci0.present"`.

Using `VixVM_WriteVariable()` to change this variable to enable VIX in a machine where it isn't enabled doesn't seem to be supported.

Is there another way to do this enable VIX programmatically from another VM? Any way to do this other than the GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Is VMWare Tools installed on the virtual machine?

If not, I believe you can call the InstallTools vix api function to install the VMWare Tools on the virtual machine, and then you should be able to interact with the vm using the other vix api calls.